# Trigger.io Local Resource Access on Android 4.4

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, trigger.io

I have a very simple HTML5 app written with trigger.io that fails running under Android 4.4 with errors stating that local content cannot be accessed. Example:

```
E/AndroidProtocolHandler( 2236): Unable to open content URL: content:////io.trigger.forge9aee7db8338b11e4b77d1231392b77b0/src/images/connect4.jpg
```

The same code works find under Android 4.3. This applies to all local content including images, CSS and JavaScript.  All resources are referenced with relative paths such as "images/image.jpg".

My best guess is that there is an access policy change in newer versions of Android OS but I cannot figure out the details. I have made sure that nowhere in the code attempts to access external resources.

Answer (score 2):

Antoine van Gelder was incredibly helpful on this. His diagnosis was absolutely correct that jQuery Mobile is rewriting the URLs for resources which causes newer versions of Android's Chrome Webview to fail when accessing resources.  The generated URLs contain quadruple slashes after the protocol like this:

content:////io.trigger.forge9aee7db8338b11e4b77d1231392b77b0/src/resource.png

The extra slashes cause Webview to fail.  Possibly some excessive checking for correctness or a security implication?

Antoine's suggestions of using older versions of jQuery Mobile or building a custom jQuery Mobile without Base Tag will probably work in some circumstances though neither was quite sufficient in my case.  Particularly, removing Base Tag also removes some other functionality I needed.

An alternative approach is to make a minor hack to jQuery Mobile.  For version 1.4.3 I did the following:

- Edited an un-minified version of jQuery Mobile's javascript
- Modified the getLocation function:

  - Save the return value to a temporary variable
  - Modify the temporary variable by removing quadruple slashes.
  - I used something very specific and restricted to the "content" protocol: "retVal = retVal.replace("content:////","content://");"
- Return the fixed temporary variable

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, starting with v1.3, jQuery Mobile are rewriting the URL's in your document which breaks the Chrome Webview's access to files in the app sandbox.

You could try filing a bug report with the jQuery Mobile devs but to sort this out in the short term your best options are probably one of:

1) Fall back to jQuery Mobile 1.2.1

2) Build a custom version of jQuery Mobile which excludes some navigation features. (Go to download builder (http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/), scroll down to "Navigation" and de-select the "Base Tag" module)

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed in JqueryMobile 1.4.4.